# Pandas divide alle columns by its max skip first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one Datetimecolumn and many data columns.
I want to normalize all the mean columns. Since they are already all positiv and starting from 0 I simply need to devide them by their max.

My data looks like this:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00    4    0    0
2015-02-01 00:00:00    4    5    4
2015-03-01 00:00:00    0    5    3
2015-04-01 00:00:00    2    5    4
```

So what I did was:

```
df = df / df.max()
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeArray
```

Which makes sense. However I do not want to iterato oven all colums and fill in their names doing it one by one.
I am guessing there is a better way to exclude one column.
I considered copying the dataframe dropping the column, performing the operation and remerging. But it seems very ugly.

I am looking forward to your suggestions, thank you.

Edit:
Now have a working solution:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'timestamp'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'timestamp'] / df.loc[:, df.columns != 'timestamp'].max()
```

Still think it could be more efficient.

Comment: what is the expected output? do you want to overwrite your current columns or create new ones?

Comment: I want to overwrite. I actually now have a working solution. I edited my question. Still think it could be better maybe.

Comment: and you would like to normalize all your numerical columns in your dataframe?

Comment: Thanks! now found multiply ways to do it that are all nicer than what I started with.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `df`, with `dtypes`:

```
df
    datetime  col1  col2  col3
0 2015-01-01     4     0     0
1 2015-02-01     4     5     4
2 2015-03-01     0     5     3
3 2015-04-01     2     5     4

df.dtypes 
datetime    datetime64[ns]
col1                 int64
col2                 int64
col3                 int64
dtype: object
```

Perhaps you could get your columns you want to normalize in a `list` (I assume you want to normalize all your numeric columns), and then apply the same calculation on all of them:

```
numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtypes != 'O' and df[col].dtypes != 'datetime64[ns]']

for i in numeric_cols:
    df[i] = df[i] / df[i].max()
```

Which will overwrite your current **numeric** columns and leave your datetime (and other categorical) columns intact:

```
df
Out[21]: 
    datetime  col1  col2  col3
0 2015-01-01   1.0   0.0  0.00
1 2015-02-01   1.0   1.0  1.00
2 2015-03-01   0.0   1.0  0.75
3 2015-04-01   0.5   1.0  1.00
```